# Shortcut for zoom to data driven page extent?

Tags: arcmap, data-driven-pages, shortcuts

I would like a shortcut to return my (data) view to the current data driven page extent.  Somewhat like having a bookmarked view, if the bookmark updated with the current data driven page.

Since I don't think such a thing exists, I thought I would create a customized keyboard shortcut.  But I haven't any idea what command I could set the shortcut for.

My work-around, and the behavior I would like to emulate, is to put the cursor in the text box on the Data Driven Pages toolbar, and then move it elsewhere - click somewhere else or press enter.  Anyone know how to put this into a keyboard shortcut?

Perhaps I should add that I'm using ArcMap 10.4.1.

Comment: I don't have an MXD with DDP handy but IIRC the Refresh button on the DDP toolbar does this.

Comment: It. is called Next Page.

Comment: @DanC, IIUC the Refresh button does much more - refreshing the current setup of the pages.  Maybe not important for small files, but I have many hundreds of pages.  Certainly a possibility, though.

Comment: @FelixIP, Next Page advances to the next page.  I want to restore the view to the current page.  (e.g. after zooming in or panning away.)

Comment: Do previous after